# Sum(Column1) and Show in Column2 in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Need a query for following Output..

```
ID  Column1  Column2
1     50       220
2     60       220
3     40       220 
4     10       220
5     25       220
6     35       220
```

I need a SELECT Query to sum(column1) and show the result in column2

Comment: What is your mysql version ?

Comment: what's your DBMS `mysql` or `sql-server`..?

Comment: Removed SQL Server tag as OP has accepted MySQL based answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*, sum(col1) over ()  as col2
from table t;
```

However, MySQL doesn't have window functionality if you are working with older version, so you can use `subquery` instead :

```
select t.*, (select sum(t1.col1) from table t1) as col2
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily solved using [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) in MySQL version >= 8.0.

In Older MySQL versions, you can get the overall [`Sum`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) separately in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). Then, do a `Cross Join` with your main table, and `Select` fields accordingly:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
       t1.Column1, 
       t2.sum_total AS Column2 
FROM your_table AS t1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(Column1) AS sum_total
            FROM your_table) AS t2 
ORDER BY t1.ID ASC
```

**Note** that Derived table based approach would be efficient than using a Subquery in the `Select`. In this approach, computation of `Sum` will happen only once; while the other approach will compute for every row.

### [Rextester DEMO](https://rextester.com/IRSZ55664)

**Demo Output:**

[image]